# How to add parameter popup on a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a cursor which takes data from a table and copy to another table for a particular time period with `fromdate` and `todate` parameters:

```
select * from table where fromdate = date1 and todate = date2
```

When I run the script it should open a popup to enter the from date and to date to enter the parameters.

Can we do this in oracle SQL developer cursor.

Answer (score 2):

How about option you can reuse *indefinitely*? If you use that anonymous PL/SQL block, you'll have to keep SQL Developer open, or save code into a file so that you could open it and run when needed.

If you switch to a stored procedure, it'll stay *in the database* and be ready for future use. Something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_date_from in date) is
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select ename, hiredate
  4                  from emp
  5                  where hiredate >= par_date_from   --> this is your parameter
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename ||' '|| to_char(cur_r.hiredate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Use it like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    p_test (date '1982-01-01');      --> date parameter passed to a procedure
  3  end;
  4  /
SCOTT 09.12.1982
ADAMS 12.01.1983
MILLER 23.01.1982

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a complete script providing more context, it looks like you want to use a bind variables:

```sql
select * from table where fromdate = :date1 and todate = :date2
```

SQL Developer should provide a pop-up allowing you to define the variables (provided you do not define them programmatically).

You could also try substitution variables:

```sql
select * from table where fromdate = &date1 and todate = &date2
```

Comment: SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sampletable
    WHERE
      
         r.request_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(from_date, &date1) AND TO_DATE(to_date, &date2)    i get the below error if i execute this with parameter 
ORA-00904: "TO_DATE": ongeldige ID
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"